# Eliminar la primera parte de una url en un src de las imagenes

Tags: javascript

> src="public/img/imagen.jpg"

quisiera que sea

> src="img/imagen.jpg"

gracias.

Comment: Debes poner aquello que haz intentado, literalmente pusiste en tu pregunta "No se como hacerlo, haganlo ustedes". No haz intentado nada literalmente

Comment: Bienvenido! Te recomiendo leer [ask] y completar el [tour] para conocer mejor SOes y entender qué tipo de preguntas esperamos. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta y añadir más detalles para que podamos ayudarte y la pregunta podrá ser reabierta

Answer (score 2):

No das mucho contexto de tu problema, pero con lo que entiendo podrías hacer algo como:

```js
const originalUrl = "public/img/imagen.jpg"
const formatedUrl = originalUrl.split("/").slice(1).join("/");
```

otra alternativa sería haciendo uso de expresiones regulares, aqui te dejo un link con más información.

[Expresiones Regulares - Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Para poder brindarte una mejor respuesta es necesario que des mas contexto de tu problema y un avance de lo que haz intentado.